# С запятыми или с тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

`Самое интересное — конец — вы как раз не показываете.`

`Самое интересное, конец, вы как раз не показываете.`

Какой из них верен? Может, оба? Не надо говорить, какой **лучше**, — мне нужно знать, какой/какие верны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

*Самое интересное, **конец**, вы как раз не показываете.*

Или так: *Самое интересное, **а именно конец**, вы как раз не показываете.*

**Пояснение**

1. Вариант с **симметричным** знаком (два тире) не подойдет. Вставка должна быть смещена **к первой части**, а по правилам это сделать нельзя.
2. **Обособленное приложение** со значением пояснения? Пояснение — это обозначение одного и того же понятия другими словами. Обычно для обособления используются запятые, вариант с тире нужно **обосновать**.

Должен быть **особый характер пояснения** (дополнительные сведения), тогда вместо запятых используется **тире**. Другими словами, это пояснение, оформленное как **присоединение.**

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

По **[Розенталю п. 10(3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)**

При обособлении приложений **вместо запятой** употребляется **тире**:  3) для выделения (с двух сторон) приложения, носящего **характер пояснения:** Какая-то ненатуральная зелень — творение скучных беспрерывных дождей — покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы (Г.); Лёгкие судороги — **признак сильного чувства** — пробежали по его широким губам (Т.); Смотритель ночлежки — **отставной солдат скобелевских времён** — шёл следом за хозяином (Фед.); Память об Авиценне — **выдающемся учёном-энциклопедисте**, борце за разум и прогресс — дорога для всего человечества (Газ.); Ловили рыбу бреднем — **маленьким неводом** — да вёршами-ловушками; Достали глубиномер — **гирьку на длинной бечёвке** — и промерили глубину; Он — **инвалид** — продолжал работать и помогать другим.

Comment: Я два тире подразумевал как пояснение (ведь, как вы сами написали, можно поставить союз _а именно_!), а не как вставку.

Comment: От названия суть не меняется (вставка, пояснение, уточнение, присоединение).  В устной разговорной речи  две одинаковые (подчеркнутые) паузы сюда не подойдут, а на письме  такая запись выглядит необоснованно.

Comment: Ну, я подумаю пока над вашим ответом. :)

Comment: Что ж думать? Хороший ответ. Берите!

Comment: Мне кажется, тире всë-таки можно, если сбелать больше паузу и т. д.

Comment: Я бы сказала – не запрещается,  это  зависит от ситуации.  И предложила бы  такой вариант со вставкой: Самое интересное — конец!  — вы как раз не показываете.  Как вам?  Здесь интонационно обозначено смещение.  И графически симметрии нет.

Comment: Такой вариант тоже можно. Только у меня не вставка и не восклицание, а пояснительный характер. А с запятыми утоснение или приложение? На уточнение не похоже, т. к. можно союз А ИМЕННО поставить. Думаю, приложение, если с запятыми.

Comment: Философский вопрос, Максим)) Много чего можно сказать... Задайте его отдельно, я бы тоже послушала)  А с пояснением вы не уходите от неопределенности. Это семантика,  а ориентироваться  лучше на грамматику.